# how to filter through json object

Tags: javascript, json, loops

**Javascript**

```
var obj = { 
    "name" : ["alex","bob","ajhoge"],
    "age" : [30,31,33]
};
```

to output "alex" for instance

```
document.write(obj["name"][0])
```

so how to filter through obj to fetch all data like

**html**

```
<ul>
  <li>name
     <ul>
       <li>alex</li>
       <li>bob</li>
       <li>ajhoge</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
  <li>age
     <ul>
       <li>30</li>
       <li>31</li>
       <li>33</li>
     </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var x;
for (x in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(x)) {
        <li>x</ul>
        <ul>
        obj[x].forEach(function (elem) {
            return "<li>" + elem + "</li>";
        });
        </ul>
    }
}
```

You could work with something of this kind. Please note

1. Do not use an document.write
2. The inner loops inside the for are pseudo code.